# SQL Server float number in varchar type that needs to be converted back to float type

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, varchar

I have an issue with a `varchar` float number e.g 2.045.030 which needs to be converted to `float` from `varchar`.

When trying to use any of the `try_parse`, `try_convert`, `try_cast` functions I get NULL instead of the converted value.

This is on a SQL server database.

Did anyone have a similar issue?

Comment: `2.045.030` data have two point. it isn't a valid float.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the values are formatted with `.` as thousands separator (and `,` as decimal point), so remove the points and replace a comma by the decimal point:

```
DECLARE @num varchar(50) = '2.045.030,725';
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@num, '.', ''), ',', '.') AS float);
```

Result: 2045030.725

Comment: One could also just replace the periods with empty string and use `TRY_PARSE` with a culture that uses comma decimal separators: `TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(@num, '.', '') AS float USING 'pt-PT')`

Comment: I think i found a way need to test and see if it will work for all cases as they are a lot unfortunately.

Comment: Try_convert(FLOAT,CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING('2.045.030',1,PATINDEX('%.%','2.045.030')),'.',''),SUBSTRING('2.045.030',PATINDEX('%.%','2.045.030')+1,LEN(2.045.030))))

Comment: @user2719567 Well, if 2045.03 is the number you wanted… your expression will remove the first thousands separator and interprete the second one as a decimal point. And it will fail with a third one: 2.045.030.123